# PHP U.S TimeZones Map?

Tags: php, timezone

So I was working with the DateTimeZone class in php and was able to print out a list of all the timezones in the United States.  I printed it down below.

Only issue is I'm afraid the users will not understand what this means? I put it all in a drop-down but say you live in Florida for example, does the average person really know which one of these would be there timezone choice? I think it would be far easier to show PST, EST, MNT, CST or HAST, HST or AKST.  Is there a way to still use the DateTimeZone class using the abbreviations PST, EST etc...?

By still use I mean, be able to convert between different times, like 2:00 PST convert to EST etc...?

```
'America/Adak',
'America/Anchorage',
'America/Boise',
'America/Chicago',
'America/Denver',
'America/Detroit',
'America/Indiana/Indianapolis',
'America/Indiana/Knox',
'America/Indiana/Marengo',
'America/Indiana/Petersburg',
'America/Indiana/Tell_City',
'America/Indiana/Vevay',
'America/Indiana/Vincennes',
'America/Indiana/Winamac',
'America/Juneau',
'America/Kentucky/Louisville',
'America/Kentucky/Monticello',
'America/Los_Angeles',
'America/Menominee',
'America/Metlakatla',
'America/New_York',
'America/Nome',
'America/North_Dakota/Beulah',
'America/North_Dakota/Center',
'America/North_Dakota/New_Salem',
'America/Phoenix',
'America/Shiprock',
'America/Sitka',
'America/Yakutat',
'Pacific/Honolulu'
```

Comment: What about [timezone_abbreviations_list()](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.timezone-abbreviations-list.php)? That shows the abbreviations, like `est`.

Comment: can you show me a code example for that?

Comment: Also I created this list from that, which is the problem.

Comment: For example, $dateTime = new DateTime(); 
$dateTime->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles')); 
return $dateTime->format('T'); This requires that I already know 'America/Los_Angeles' before hand.  What I need is something where I only know PST or EST etc.

Comment: The problem is that the average person won't know whether to use PST or PDT, EST or EDT, and if you use CST/CDT, you won't necessarily know  that it means Central time in the USA, there are 5 locations that use the abbreviation CST.  In your title, you mentioned a map, but didn't ask in the question.  But perhaps you were looking for something like [this](https://github.com/dosx/timezone-picker) or [this](http://timezonepicker.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
// Show to the user
$options = array();
foreach ( timezone_abbreviations_list() as $abbr => $tz ) {
  $options[ $tz[0]['timezone_id'] ] = strtoupper($abbr);
}
// array('America/Porto_Acre' => 'ACST', ...)

// Use
$user_timezone_id = ... somewhere in account? ...
date_default_timezone_set($user_timezone_id);
```

Or something like that. The user chooses from abbreviations like ACST and EST, and the system uses timezone id's in the background.

If you know `EST` somehow, but you don't know `America/New_York`, you can do:

```
$user_timezone_abbr = ... somewhere in account? ...
$timezones = timezone_abbreviations_list();
$timezone_id = $timezones[$user_timezone_abbr][0]['timezone_id'];
date_default_timezone_set($user_timezone_id);
```

or something like that.

Comment: Your solution is really good, thanks!